UDP socket-to-socket communication problems
After UDP is connected to the socket, the client sends a message, the server receives it, outputs it, and tries to send his message to the client. After that, I want to post this message on the client, but it doesn't seem to pick it up, what's the problem?
After sending a message from the client, the server receives it, outputs it, and tries to send his message to the client. And then receiving this message from the client
THis is client udp socket.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 30
void error_handling(char *message);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    char message[BUF_SIZE];
    char clntmessage[BUF_SIZE];
    char servmessage[BUF_SIZE];
    int str_len;
    socklen_t adr_sz;
    
    struct sockaddr_in serv_adr, from_adr;
    if(argc!=3){
        printf("Usage : %s <IP> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    sock=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);   
    if(sock==-1)
        error_handling("socket() error");
    
    memset(&serv_adr, 0, sizeof(serv_adr));
    serv_adr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_adr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
    serv_adr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[2]));
    
    while(1)
    {
        fputs("Insert message(q or Q quit): ", stdout);
        fgets(clntmessage, sizeof(message), stdin);   
        sendto(sock, clntmessage, strlen(clntmessage), 0,
            (struct sockaddr*)&serv_adr, sizeof(serv_adr));

        if (!strcmp(clntmessage, "q\n") || !strcmp(clntmessage, "Q\n")) {
            adr_sz = sizeof(from_adr);
            str_len = recvfrom(sock, servmessage, BUF_SIZE, 0,
                (struct sockaddr*)&from_adr, &adr_sz);
            printf("Message from server: %s", servmessage);
            if (!strcmp(servmessage, "bye\n"))
                break;
            else 
                servmessage[str_len] = 0;
                printf("Message from server: %s", servmessage);
                continue;

    }
    
    adr_sz=sizeof(from_adr);
    str_len=recvfrom(sock, servmessage, BUF_SIZE, 0, 
                (struct sockaddr*)&from_adr, &adr_sz);

    servmessage[str_len]=0;
    printf("Message from server: %s", servmessage);
}   
close(sock);
return 0;

}
void error_handling(char *message)
{
    fputs(message, stderr);
    fputc('\n', stderr);
    exit(1);
}

This is server udp socket.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 30
void error_handling(char *message);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int serv_sock;
    char send_message[BUF_SIZE];
    char recv_message[BUF_SIZE];
    int str_len;
    socklen_t clnt_adr_sz;
    
    struct sockaddr_in serv_adr, clnt_adr;
    if(argc!=2){
        printf("Usage : %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    serv_sock=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(serv_sock==-1)
        error_handling("UDP socket creation error");
    
    memset(&serv_adr, 0, sizeof(serv_adr));
    serv_adr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_adr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_adr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    
    if(bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_adr, sizeof(serv_adr))==-1)
        error_handling("bind() error");

    while(1) 
    {
        //받는 곳

        str_len = recvfrom(serv_sock, recv_message, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clnt_adr, &clnt_adr_sz);
    

        if (!strcmp(recv_message, "q\n") || !strcmp(recv_message, "Q\n")) {
            sendto(serv_sock, "bye", 4, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clnt_adr, clnt_adr_sz);
            printf("Message received from Client: %s", recv_message);
            break;
        }
        recv_message[str_len] = 0;
        printf("Message received from Client: %s", recv_message);

        
        //보내는 곳
        fputs("Insert message: ", stdout);
        fgets(send_message, sizeof(send_message), stdin);
        sendto(serv_sock, send_message, strlen(send_message), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clnt_adr, sizeof(clnt_adr));
        
    }   
    close(serv_sock);
    return 0;
}

void error_handling(char *message)
{
    fputs(message, stderr);
    fputc('\n', stderr);
    exit(1);
}



Are you testing with the server and client programs running on the same machine, or on different machines?  If it's different machines, you might check to see if the client machine is running a firewall that blocks incoming UDP packets.

Also you need to check the return values of all of the functions you call, because if you don't check them you won't know if the function succeeded or failed.  e.g. instead of just calling sendto(...);, do something like int r = sendto(...); if (r != 0) perror("sendto"); so that you'll be able to see in your program's output where things went wrong.

Oops, I should have written if (r == -1) perror("sendto");

I believe your problem is here, in the server code:
socklen_t clnt_adr_sz;

[...]

while(1) 
{
    //받는 곳
    str_len = recvfrom(serv_sock, recv_message, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clnt_adr, &clnt_adr_sz);
    [...]

Note that you never initialize clnt_adr_sz to any value, which means its value is indeterminate when you pass a pointer to it into recvfrom() later on.  Since recvfrom() is only authorized to write up to clnt_adr_size bytes of address-data into clnt_adr, it's likely that the value in clnt_adr_sz is too small (maybe zero) and therefore clnt_adr doesn't get properly filled out by the recvfrom() call.
To fix it, I recommend adding this line just before each recvfrom() call:
clnt_adr_sz = sizeof(clnt_adr);

